# Health implications of bean bag chairs

Tags: posture, ergonomics

What are the health implications of using bean bag chairs regularly for multiple hours a day (such as when working in one of them with a laptop)? Can bean bag chairs be considered ergonomic under these circumstances?

Has research regarding this issue been done? I tried to find material in this direction but all I could come up with was advertising and anecdotic claims.
[image]

Comment: Using bean bags in what way? Do you mean bean bag chairs?

Comment: Yes. I've added an image for clarification.